# Cannot load Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET web application that works fine at my desk but when I deploy it to the server I'm getting this error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

My project targets the .NET 4.6.1 framework and both machines have 4.8 installed. I already had the latest Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces NuGet package installed so I attempted to revert to version 1.1 instead of the latest 5.0 and that didn't fix it.

I'm not sure what else to check. The Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll is in the bin folder.

Comment: So I have narrowed this down further. It's not just Bcl, it's other Nuget packages too. I uninstalled Json and Bcl and the next error I got was it couldn't reference Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. So, apparently I don't know how to deploy my web app when it has NuGet package references. Any ideas on what I should be checking for? Or maybe I am not updating enough files. I usually just compile everything and put it in the bin folder. If I update a .ASPX file I update that too but that's usually it.

Comment: If using Visual Studio, use the "Publish" action to have all the content properly placed into a destination folder before copying it to the server. I've found that a simple "Build" from Visual Studio requires a lot more work to get everything properly copied to the server. Besides the `bin` folder, most the `*.as?x` files in multiple folders must also be copied, along with static assets. Also, ensure that dependencies are included in the publish - "copy always" or "copy if newer".